# calling rtk query hook inside slice reducer ? is this right practice

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

import { useGetAllProductsQuery } from '../../api';

const initialState={
    products:[],
    loading:false,
    count:5,
    error:[]
}

export const productSlice=createSlice({
    name:'product',
    initialState,
    reducers:{
        productListRequest:(state,action)=>{
            const {data,isLoading,isFetching,error,isError,isSuccess}=useGetAllProductsQuery();
            state.count=state.count+1
            state.products.push(data)
        },
```

error is

[1]   Line 16:71:  React Hook "useGetAllProductsQuery" is called in function "productListRequest" that is neither a React function component nor a custom React Hook function. React component names must start with an uppercase letter. React Hook names must start with the word "use"  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks

what's the right way to store response data to store using toolkit and rtk

Comment: You dont need to store the data, its already available in the `data` key of `useGetAllProductsQuery` hook. `redux-toolkit` already does that for you

Comment: i know that but i want to take that data and store it in my local state , how to do that i am asking??

Comment: You would be duplicating data in your store, that is a bad practice (data redundancy/inconsistency). Buuut if you still want to do it, you would have to dispatch the `data` from `useGetAllProductsQuery` inside a component using `dispatch(productListRequest(data))`